# Compute a statistic (coohend) between all the columns of a dataframe (using apply family function)

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Concentration  Value
Low            0.21
Medium         0.85    
Low            0.10
Low            0.36
High           2.21
Medium         0.50
High           1.85
```

With the pivot_wider function you can transform this into a dataframe where each column is a value of the other variable:

```
Low           Medium         High
c(0.21,...)   c(0.87 ,...)   c(1.47 ,...)
```

There's a function called `cohen.d()` from the `library(effsize)` package, that allows you to calculate the effect size between two groups.
You could do, for exmaple, `cohen.d(dat$Low, dat$Medium)` to obtain the effect size between this two columns.

In this case, however, I would like to use a function from the apply family to compute the cohend between the Low column, and all the rest variables.

Comment: don't forget the curly braces around the function body

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, there is an error ` Error in tapply(seq_len(1L), list(group = c(-0.04, 0, -0.1, -0.02, -0.00999999999999998,  : 
  arguments must have same length ` Has the dataframe columns have different distances

Comment: I added a solution. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R idea can be,

```
library(effsize)

l3 <- split(dd$Value, dd$Concentration)
lapply(l3[!names(l3) %in% 'Low'], function(i)cohen.d(l3$Low, i))
$High

Cohen's d

d estimate: -9.952077 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
      lower       upper 
-20.3804615   0.4763081 


$Medium

Cohen's d

d estimate: -2.533928 (large)
95 percent confidence interval:
    lower     upper 
-6.399536  1.331680
```

**DATA**

```
dput(dd)
structure(list(Concentration = c("Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "Medium", "High"), Value = c(0.21, 0.85, 0.1, 0.36, 2.21, 
0.5, 1.85)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```